# How to make a popup dialog appear on all devices connected to my WiFi, like with msg.exe or net send but cross platform?

Tags: iphone, html, networking, wifi, msg

I'd like to have a popup dialog box come up on all devices connected to my WiFi, say with the message "OK, you only get 15 mins of free WiFi".  Is there anyways I can broadcast this to all devices currently on my WiFi?

Answer (score 0):

Not without running something on all devices.

Comment: well, is there anything running on "most devices" like msg.exe running on vista and win 7.  Can the iOS push technology be used without installing anything on the device?

Comment: No. There is nothing that can receive your messages, other then your own application.